# TFS 2015 API ignores ChangedBy

Tags: api, workitem, tfs-2015

I have a WebApplication that creates and changes WorkItems through the API. I want the "ChangedBy" field  be set to a specific string-value. This worked well with TFS 2013.
After upgrading to TFS 2015 my value is ignored and ChangedBy is always set to the identity of the user that I use for connecting to the TFS.

This is my code:

```
//Set some values on the WorkItem
item.Fields["ChangedBy"].Value = "MyUserName";
item.Save();
```

Is there a way to enforce the behaviour like it was in TFS 2013?

Comment: Have you tried to do the same with the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items#UpdateworkitemsUpdateafield)?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/17/work-item-field-attributes-what-you-can-and-can-t-change.aspx), by default, the Changed By field is one of the non-editable fields (set by the system). In order to modify it, you need to use work with WorkItemStore object in **BypassRule** mode. Bypass Rule allow you to modify the work item fields without any restrictions, so you can change the **Changed By** field.

Define your code as:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tfctc, WorkItemStoreFlags.BypassRules);
        WorkItem workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workitemid);
        string changedBy = (string)workItem.Fields["Changed By"].Value;
        workItem.Fields["Changed By"].Value = "User Name";
```

Comment: The documentation does not match my experience with TFS 2013. I was able to change that field to whatever I wanted. It stopped working in TFS 2015, so maybe they fixed that bug.

Comment: Bypass rules is not an option for me, because I want to change other fields and have them be checked against the rules.